# Big Oh : How can i prove or disprove $8^{(n-3) }= O(2^n)$

Tags: asymptotics

How would I prove or disprove this?

I tried it like this:

$$8^{n-3}\in O\left(2^n\right)$$
$$8^{n-3}\leq c\cdot 2^n$$
$$8^n\cdot8^{-3}\leq c\cdot 2^n$$
$$8^n\leq c\cdot 2^n$$

(We can remove the $8^{-3}$ because it is a constant)

But I'm really unsure. Is this even correct? What would c have to be then?

Comment: It is not true.

Comment: Could you please explain why?

Comment: Coul *you* explain why it would be true ?

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is false that $8^{n-3} = O(2^n)$. Indeed,
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{8^{n-3}}{2^n} = \limsup_{n\to\infty} 2^{2n-9} = \infty,$$
which contradicts the definition of $f=O(g)$, i.e., that
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{|f(n)|}{g(n)}<\infty.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

$8^n = 2^n\cdot 4^n$. Think about the $4^n$ and how it can outgrow any constant $C$.

Answer (score 2):

$8^{n-3}=O(2^n)$ means that the sequence $a_n= \frac{8^{n-3}}{2^n}$ is bounded. But $a_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty.$

Consequence: $8^{n-3}=O(2^n)$  is not true.

Comment: Why the downvote ??

Answer (score 2):

Divide both sides by $2^n$ and you should get $$\frac{8^n}{2^n}=\left(\frac82\right)^n=4^n\leq c$$
Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}4^n=\infty$, i.e. $4^n$ diverges, there cannot exist constant $c$ such that $4^n\leq c$ for all $n$.

Therefore $8^{n-3}\notin O\left(2^n\right)$

Answer (score 1):

Taking the base-$2$ logarithm,

$$3(n-3)\le\log_2c+n$$ or $$\log_2c\ge 2n-6$$ is certainly not possible.